# Laravel Cache - file_put_contents file not found

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.4

I have this really strange error that I'm struggling to figure out.

I have a command that will cache the homepage. If I run `cache:clear` then `command:updateCaches`

And then try and load the site it tells me

```
file_put_contents(/home/sites/staff.habbocreate.com/storage/framework/cache/data/80/b6/80b69166730ee957730d0770e96781dbd90ae953): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /home/sites/staff.habbocreate.com/resources/views/frontend/home.blade.php)
```

Its like being logged out causes the error. Except, I can cache the first time without being logged in via my browser and that works no problem.

Here is HomeController.php https://pastebin.com/P1uNNWEs

I don't expect anyone to figure it out, just an idea why it might be going wrong. Any help would appreciated though.

Comment: It could be a permission problem, check that

Comment: root:www-data and 775 on storage folder so I don't think thats it

Comment: The final folder, e.g. `b6` doesn't exist, not sure if that helps.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Any luck founded?

Comment: I tried dump-autoload. Still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out it was my own stupidity causing the error.

I was running the command via terminal so when the data files were created, they were created with the users and group root.

Then when I tried to view it in the browser, the user www-data was unable to access them.

Comment: the data directory ownership was my issue as well as the cache file/directories could not be created by php... chown to _www:wheel solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score -1):

try use **public** word

```
file_put_contents(/home/sites/staff.habbocreate.com/public/storage/framework/cache/data/80/b6/80b69166730ee957730d0770e96781dbd90ae953);
```

Comment: Adding public will just change the location